# The metadata could not be determined because the statement <SELECT Statement 1> is not compatible with the statement <SELECT Statement 2>

Tags: sql-server, ssis, odbc, oledb

There are about 100 packages deployed to SSIS server. All the packages are the same. All of them had worked for a long time. However, on one certain day all of them started failing with the same error:

> "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005 
>   Description: "The metadata could not be determined because the
>   statement 'SELECT TOP 1
>              1 [TableName]
>       FROM
>       (
>           SELECT TOP 1
>                   1 [Ta' is not compatible with the statement 'SELECT TOP 1
>              1 [TableName]
>       FROM sys.[tables]
>       WHERE 1 = 0'. 
>   End Error  Error: 2019-11-15 12:39:20.40     Code: 0xC020204A
>   Source:       Description: Unable to retrieve column
>   information from the data source. Make sure your target table in the
>   database is available.  End Error  Error: 2019-11-15 12:39:20.42
>   Code: 0xC004706B     Source:   SSIS.Pipeline
>   Description:  failed validation and returned validation
>   status "VS_ISBROKEN".  End Error  Error: 2019-11-15 12:39:20.42
>   Code: 0xC004700C     Source:   SSIS.Pipeline
>   Description: One or more component failed validation.  End Error 
>   Error: 2019-11-15 12:39:20.43     Code: 0xC0024107     Source:        Description: There were errors during task validation. 
>   End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1). 
>   Started:  12:39:19 PM  Finished: 12:39:20 PM  Elapsed:  1.234 seconds.
>   The package execution failed.  The step failed.

The simplified version of the statement which fails validation looks like this:

```
IF
(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM sys.[tables]
    WHERE [is_ms_shipped] = 0
          AND modify_date > '10/24/2019 11:33:00 AM'
) > 0
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1
           1 [TableName]
    FROM
    (
        SELECT TOP 1
                1 [TableName]
        FROM sys.[tables] AS T
        WHERE T.[is_ms_shipped] = 0
              AND T.modify_date > '10/24/2019 11:33:00 AM'
    UNION ALL
        SELECT TOP 1
                1 [TableName]
        FROM sys.views AS T
        WHERE T.[is_ms_shipped] = 0
              AND T.modify_date > '10/24/2019 11:33:00 AM'
    ) q
END;
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1
           1 [TableName]
    FROM sys.[tables]
    WHERE 1 = 0;
END
```

Both selects return the same columns with the same data types.
I know that I can rewrite this statement so that no error is returned.
And I did this for a couple of packages and deployed them.

However, the problem is that the packages cannot be easily replaced due to internal reasons. I need to figure out what happened and why this error appeared all of a sudden for all the packages and to restore the conditions in which the packages worked.
On the day before the issue the following Windows updates were installed on the machine where SSIS servers is running:

- 2019-11  Cumulative Update for Windows Server 2016 for x64-based
  Systems (KB4525236).
  This included "Security updates for ... the
  Microsoft JET Database Engine"
- 2019-12  Servicing Stack Update for Windows Server 2016 for x64-based
  Systems (KB4520724).
  Seemed to be nothing related to SQL.

What I did:

- I uninstalled the first update (KB4525236). (The second update
  (KB4520724) is un-uninstallable)
- I checked the versions of the ODBC Driver and aligned them with the versions that are installed on another environment where this same
  package still executed successfully.

  [ODBC Driver versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPOhy.png)

Didn’t help.

There are the following platform versions that are used:

- SSIS server – version 13.0.5101.9
- Source Server (accessed via OLE DB Source – Native OLE DB\SQL Server
  Native Client 11.0) – version 13.0.5492.2

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: That error happens when there are a different number of columns in the if-else branches but also for different data types. Data type differences can happen when there are computed values in one of the if-else branches not duplicated in the other, especially mathematical operations but also CAST() and CONVERT() operations. For example `if (condition) begin select modify_date from sys.tables end else begin select '2019-10-24' from sys.tables end` if modify_date was of `date` type then the second branch should cast the string to a `date` as well.

Comment: And to add to my own comment, column names need to be the same as well. Given your code example can I assume that the code in your SSIS packages is generated on a regular basis to update the modified_date values? Could the code generator have changed around this time? Or itself been affected by the CU/SSU packages?

Comment: Just confirming. You are saying that the above query fails validation on your server, as written?

Comment: Try running each portion of the query and placing its output in a #temp table, then identify the data types in the output tables. If there is a difference, then I'm still confused as to why, but at least we will have some more information to work with.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, the query is generated by an SSIS expression where modify_date changes dynamically with each package run. The above query fails validation on the SSIS server, as written. But before Nov, 13 there where no validation errors on the server (only in VS). The code generator could not have changed, at least for all the packages at the same time. I assume that the validation rules might have been affected by the CU/SSU packages. I tried uninstalling the CU package, but it didn't help.

Comment: @Laughing Vergil, the both parts of the if-else return the same data type and the same column names. I already checked this.